# Extract folder content from 7z archive to specific folder

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip

I have a 7z archive file which, at the "root" level, contains a couple of files and then a directory, which in turn contains both files and folders, like this:

```
- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- my_dir
    - file3.txt
    - file4.txt
    - another_dir
        - file5.txt
        - file6.txt
```

I would like to know if there is a single command that allows me to extract the **content** of `my_dir` inside a directory of my choice so that the end result is:

```
- target_dir
    - file3.txt
    - file4.txt
    - another_dir
        - file5.txt
        - file6.txt
```

I have tried these commands:

```
7za x -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir my_dir
7za x -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir 'my_dir/*'
```

but both created this directory structure:

```
- target_dir
    - my_dir
        - file3.txt
        - file4.txt
        - another_dir
            - file5.txt
            - file6.txt
```

Comment: Does this work : `7z x archive.7z my_dir -y -r -otarget_dir` ?

Comment: Sadly no, same result as the commands I tried.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Is there a single command that allows extracting my_dir to a specified directory?

Yes. Use the `e` option instead of `x`:

```
7za e -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir my_dir
```

(`x` is Extract with **full paths**)

> **e (Extract) command**
>
> Extracts files from an archive to the current directory or to the
>   output directory. The output directory can be specified by -o (Set
>   Output Directory) switch.
>
> This command copies all extracted files to one directory. If you want
>   extract files with full paths, you must use x (Extract with full
>   paths) command.

Source [e (Extract) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm)

---

#### But in fact the folder in the archive contains subfolders which I'd like to preserve

In this case you need to use the original command (with `x`), and then use `move` to move the contents of `my_dir` up a level.

Something like the  following batch file (not tested):

```
@echo off
7za x -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir my_dir
move /y my_dir\* /path/to/target_dir
rd /s my_dir
endlocal
```

From the command line:

```
7za x -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir my_dir && move /y my_dir\* /path/to/target_dir && rd /s my_dir
```

#### But I'm using Linux!

Then the commands to use are:

```
#!/bin/bash
7za x -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir my_dir
mv -f my_dir/* /path/to/target_dir
rmdir my_dir
```

Or:

```
7za x -y archive.7z -o/path/to/target_dir my_dir && mv -f my_dir/* /path/to/target_dir && rmdir my_dir
```

Which can probably be simplified by someone who knows `bash` better than I do.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Move - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [RD - Remove Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)
- [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help, but I fear I may have over-simplified my question, in fact the folder in the archive contains subfolders which I'd like to preserve, see the edit.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Then you will have to use the original `x` option and then use `move` to move the contents of `my_dir` up a level.

Comment: That's what I feared, I really hoped it could be done in a single command

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Answer updated with a suggested batch file.

Comment: Thanks for the script, however my OS is CentOS, not Windows, that's why I put the "linux" tag on the question. I'll have no problem converting that to its linux equivalent, though.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Answer updated to cover using `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

### Managing multiple archives

Not sure if this was possible when the question was first asked, but there's a simpler solution that works with both `x` and `e` (`x` preserves folder structure, `e` flattens everything, so the one you're looking for is `x`):

`7z x archive.7z -opath/to/dir`

Both swtiches (here, `x` and `-o`) support wildcards:

`7z x *.7z -o*`

This would extract all .7z archives on the current directory to new subdirectories with the same name.

Source: [-o (set Output directory) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/output_dir.htm)

### Filtering to extract folders only

If the filetypes to be filtered are known, such as `.txt` in your example, `7z x archive.7z -opath/to/dir -x!*.txt` will do the trick. Alternatively, you can filter out every name that includes a dot (`.`), so every file is excluded: `7z x archive.7z -opath/to/dir -x!*.*`. Note that this will also filter out any folder including a dot (`.`) in its name

Comment: Sadly that does not help solve the problem in my original question, as of now there is no single command for doing so

Comment: If you happen to know the file types, you can use the `-x` switch, such as `7z x archive.7z -opath/to/dir -x!*.txt` . Alternatively, if your folders don't have dots in their names, you can use `7z x archive.7z -opath/to/dir -x!*.*`

Comment: And would such command maintain the relative paths as they are inside the archive, without knowing them?

Comment: That's up to you: `x` will keep the folder structure, `e` won't. `-x!*.*` will just filter the immediate contents of `archive.7z` either way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough, if you would please read the original question, it was about extracting only a part of the archive (a subfolder in it) while preserving relative folder structure.

Comment: I edited my answer to try and further explain the concepts.